# D3 placing nodes labels inside circles in Mobile Patent Suits

Tags: d3.js

I'm new to D3 and I'm using this template (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292) to visualize my graph. However, my nodes' labels are shore and I want to place them inside circles not on their right hand-side. 
Can anybody help me with that?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append circle and text inside a group element and use text-achor property to align the text to the middle.

```
var nodes = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(force.nodes())
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class","node")
    .call(force.drag);

var circles = nodes.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 6);

var texts = nodes.append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    });
```

Change tick function as shown below.

```
function tick() {
  path.attr("d", linkArc);
  nodes.attr("transform", transform);     
}
```

**Update**

[JSFiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/ebgk3d9n/) for aligning text to the center.

If you would like enclose the text label within the circle, increase the radius of circle using the length of `name` property. Note that, you will have to update the link target positions this time, to adjust the marker positions relative to the circle radius.

```
var circles = nodes.append("circle")
   .attr("r", function(d){ d.radius = d.name.length*3; return d.radius; }
);

function linkArc(d) {
    var tX = d.target.x-d.target.radius,
      dx = tX - d.source.x,
      dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
      dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
  return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + tX + "," + d.target.y;
}
```

[JSFiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/ebgk3d9n/1/)

Comment: Can you please share the whole modified script? I made your suggested changes but it doesn't display the graph correctly. Seems I'm doing something wrong.